# Basement slab water permeance and vapor barrier, and mold precautions?

Tags: basement, mold, vapor-barrier

. Hi, all!

I ran a moisture test in my basement where you put some Calcium Chloride under a plastic dome for a few days, and then measure weight before and after. I came up with general permeance in the dry looking areas (about 95 percent of the basement) of around 4.0-4.5 lbs/1000 sq ft. There's a problem spot on an inside corner that always looks a little damp. That spot was roughly 15.

Are these numbers bad?

I was thinking of putting down a vapor barrier down and then some kind of waterproof planking over it: either LVP or Linoleum. I am partial to a product called "Natural LVT SG." It adds a nice soft membrane to the floor while being a vapor barrier.

So what I am wondering is if these numbers I got are bad and if I have to do something to bring them down first. Alt, if the numbers are OK, is there something in particular I should be putting over it? One of my concerns is having a permanent layer of moisture under the floor. Unless that's not a problem? I have no idea, and I've been trying to find ideas for months at this point. Opinions seem to be all over the place.

So, all, might you have any advice for me?

Thank you!

Edit: found this nifty calculator
https://www.translatorscafe.com/unit-converter/en-US/permeability/3-5/permeability%20(0%C2%B0C)-pounds%20per%201000%20sq.%20ft%20per%2024%20hours/

Most things seem to talk about perms. Looks like converting my numbers, I get 2.8 perms for the dry-looking areas, and 10-10.5 for the damp looking inside corner